# Replace a variable with the value of another variable

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

For example I have a text file named `input.txt` with this sentence in it:

```
This is my base64 string: ${BASE64}
```

I have this variable:

```
myvar="SGVsbG8gV29ybGQuIERvIHlvdSBsaWtlIG15IGJhc2U2NCBzdHJpbmc/IFRoYXQgaXMgdmVyeSBuaWNlIQ=="
```

expected output:

```
This is my base64 string: SGVsbG8gV29ybGQuIERvIHlvdSBsaWtlIG15IGJhc2U2NCBzdHJpbmc/IFRoYXQgaXMgdmVyeSBuaWNlIQ==
```

I thought myself this command should do the work but it gives an error.

```
$ sed -i -e "s/\${BASE64}/${myvar}/g" text.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 70: unknown option to `s'
```

I tried many options and searched on the internet for hours but I cannot figure it out exactly. I think it has something to do with the `\`

At first I want to know what I am doing wrong? Secondly I want to know how to do it right. I would love an correct awk example too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem is what you said: *I think it has something to do with the /*. 
When you use with `/` as delimiter you have to be careful with the strings you use.

So you should use another delimiter in your `sed` command:

```bash
sed -i -e "s@\${BASE64}@${myvar}@g" text.txt
```

**Using awk**

```bash
myvar="SGVsbG8gV29ybGQuIERvIHlvdSBsaWtlIG15IGJhc2U2NCBzdHJpbmc/IFRoYXQgaXMgdmVyeSBuaWNlIQ=="
awk -i inplace -v var='\\$\\{BASE64\\}' -v base="$myvar" '{sub(var,base);}1'
```

---

Another way to replace variables is by using `envsubst`. If your file contains `${BASE64}` you can create a variable with the same name and replace it inside the file. But you will have to export that variable (**just once**) before you run `envsubst`:

```bash
BASE64="SGVsbG8gV29ybGQuIERvIHlvdSBsaWtlIG15IGJhc2U2NCBzdHJpbmc/IFRoYXQgaXMgdmVyeSBuaWNlIQ=="
export BASE64
#Not recommended: 
envsubst < text.txt | tee text.txt
#Or
envsubst < text.txt >  newtext.txt
mv newtext.txt text.txt
```

Comment: I wouldn't use either the sed or awk scripts for this as they'll both fail given various different contents of `myvar`, e.g. `\1`, `\t`, `\n`, `&`, `@`, etc.

Comment: @EdMorton, for the particular case in the question, the name `BASE64` strongly suggests it will contain only alphanumerics, `=` and `/`, making this safe for OP.  For the more general case, one might be able to use shell parameter substitutions to make the substitution safe, though that can look pretty impenetrable at first sight!

Comment: No need to `export` the value to all processes - you could pass it just to that command using `BASE64="$BASE64" envsubst …`

Comment: @EdMorton that's right. And a possible solution is by escaping those chars: `\\1`, `\\t`, `\\n`, `\&`, `\@` and so on but it can be very annoying. I thing that `envsubst` has no problems with that.

Comment: @TobySpeight yes! I forgot to mention that way to export. Btw, do you why `BASE64=something sed -e ...` doesn't work? (but for some commands like `envsubst` it does)

Comment: The difference there is that `envsubst` reads what's in the environment it's invoked with; the `sed` command is substituted by the shell before it's invoked.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably easier to do with Perl, since it can read the replacement string from an environment variable, so you don't need to embed it in the code:

```
repl=$myvar perl -i -pe 's/\${BASE64}/$ENV{repl}/' input.txt
```

(that should be safe and not get evaluated for any special sequences)

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ env repl="SGVsbG8g_ETCETERA_==" raku -pe 's/\$\{BASE64\}/{ %*ENV<repl> }/'  file.txt

#OR

~$ env repl="SGVsbG8g_ETCETERA_==" raku -pe 's/\$\{BASE64\}/%*ENV<repl>/'  file.txt
```

Sample Input:

```
This is my base64 string: ${BASE64}
```

Sample Output (using truncated replacement, full-length replacement works equally as well):

```
This is my base64 string: SGVsbG8g_ETCETERA_==
```

This answer is very similar to the Perl answer of @ilkkachu (Thank you!). The `env` variable is spelled a little differently: `%*ENV` is a hash containing Raku's (dynamic) Operating system environment variables, and `<repl>` is how you can call an individual key without quoting. Note the two Raku answers only differ in `{ … }` interpolating curly braces. See the NNTP thread below for source (Trick #8).

https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#index-entry-$PERCENT_SIGN*ENV
https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl6.users/2020/07/msg9004.html
https://raku.org